# Azure Functions http trigger all traffic is being routed to one instance

Tags: azure, azure-functions

There is only one instance for my Function that is handling all requests.

I have an Azure Function (Consumption Plan) to apply a watermark to a PDF from an HTTP trigger. The PDF is retrieved via an HTTP call in the Function,  watermarked and then returned in the response.

Application Insights is hooked up to monitor the performance and do some load testing. In the portal, I configure a basic load test with a static URL (100 users over 5 minutes) and run it against my function. When I inspect the live metrics, I see that one instance is processing some number of requests, and every other instance sits at 0 requests/second and with the committed memory not changing. If I increase the user count in the load test and it eventually starts to timeout processing requests instead of routing them to the additional instances.

Why is only one instance handling all the requests?

Example code simplified.

```
#r "D:\home\site\wwwroot\watermark\bin\itextsharp.dll"

using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
static BaseFont font = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN,     BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    var fetch = "http://url.to.pdf";
    log.Info(fetch);
    log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
    var pdf = await client.GetAsync(fetch);
    var stream = await pdf.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    var resp = req.CreateResponse();

    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    var reader = new PdfReader(stream);
    var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms);
    stamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;

    var pages = reader.NumberOfPages;

    for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++)
    {
        var content = stamper.GetOverContent(i);
        AddWatermark(content, "Here is some watermark text.", font, 10, Color.BLACK, reader.GetPageSize(i));
    }

    stamper.Close();

    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    resp.Content = new StreamContent(ms);
    resp.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");  

    return resp;
}

private static void AddWatermark(PdfContentByte dc, string text, BaseFont font, float fontSize, Color color, Rectangle realPageSize, Rectangle rect = null)
{
    dc.SaveState();
    dc.SetColorFill(color);
    dc.BeginText();
    dc.SetFontAndSize(font, fontSize);
    var ps = rect ?? realPageSize; /*dc.PdfDocument.PageSize is not always correct*/
    var x = (ps.Right + ps.Left) / 2;
    var y = (ps.Bottom + ps.Top) * (1.0f / 100.0f);
    dc.ShowTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_LEFT, text, x, y, 0);
    dc.EndText();
    dc.RestoreState();
}
```

Comment: It's possible that it is an app insights reporting bug. If you post your site name or a function execution id & timeframe I can take a look at the backend logs.

Comment: Also, how are you doing your testing? Are you caching an ARRAffinity cookie that's causing all your requests to hit the same instance? Are you running on the consumption plan?

Comment: I was using the Performance Testing tool in my AppInsights instance to run the test (hitting the same URL). I also ran a constant load Visual Studio load test from my machine and got similar results. I did also run a Step test that started at 10 users and grew to 100and it behaved correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the comment about ARRAfinity cookies, I found an article about setting the 'Percentage of New Users' for the load tests and that seems to have corrected the behavior.